# How to keep wine from creating directories in my home directory?

Tags: wine

I have got a wine installtion with a couple of games, most of which work fabulously. However, wine creates directories in my home for the player data, saves, etc.

Is there a way to have those in ~/.winesaves or something similar? I would prefer wine not littering my home directory.

(wine: 1.5.27, game in question was SCII and DE:IW)

---

*edit to clarify:*

Everything in ~/.wine is fine and good, but I don't want applications to create ~/GameSaves or the likes.

Comment: You could try using sudo to put the wine folders in annother user's home directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to experiment with the `sandbox` option present in `winetricks`, which may help you as all the `Wine` symlinks to `$HOME` are removed when that setting is applied to the default WINEPREFIX with `winetricks sandbox`.

However, `wine` still has your user's permissions in the home folder, and often when installing a new program, an action in the installation can trigger the sandbox to be removed. So it is not really a true 'sandbox' at all, but it may be helpful for your use case.

At the [official wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-f566a12c806a1eacaeefb7cb6419a513a773c571) it is noted that:

> Winetricks does have a sandbox verb that does at least a partial job of isolating Wine programs from the rest of your system. It protects against errors rather than malice. It's useful for, e.g., keeping games from saving their settings in random subdirectories of your home directory.

On the [official winetricks page](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/wiki/WhereAppsGo), it is explained that

> If you want to isolate an app so that it doesn't save anything to your home directory, you can try 'winetricks sandbox'. That will remove the symlinks to your home directory. Do this before saving any data, or you'll have to copy old saved data from your home directory into $WINEPREFIX/drive_c/users/$USERNAME.

**Important notes**

- The wine sandbox option will likely need to be used repeatedly, i.e. include it in a launcher script that runs `winetricks sandbox` and then launches your game, as a number of things in `wine` can trigger the rebuilding of the symlinks.
- The folder of saves you have already generated will need to be moved to your WINEPREFIX, e.g `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/"My Documents"` in order for you to resume your game. If `wine` has just created a folder called `~/gamesaves`, simply move that folder to the location mentioned above. Otherwise, observe the directory structure; if a game save folder is `~/Documents/Syberia/save` make sure you create an equivalent in `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/"My Documents"`.
- When you install a game in the future, make sure you run `winetricks sandbox` at the start, so that the game will automatically start using your WINEPREFIX as the save location, and not a folder in your `$HOME`.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Just a minor correction: Move ~/* to /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/users/$USER/*My Documents*

Comment: @user538603 Thanks, quick edit done.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution to fully block wine from modifying the home directory, but I find this works to prevent most programs from polluting my home directory, and is quite a clean solution.

Most of the time (in my experience) when a program running through wine is accessing outside the "~/.wine" folder, it's doing so through symbolic links in the "~/.wine" directory. For example, I had an installer install a folder in my home directory, when really it was trying to install in "C:/users/user name/My Documents" which wine redirects to    "~/.wine/drive_c/users/user name/My Documents". It turns out "My Documents" here is actually a symbolic link to my home directory, "~".

So simply removing the symbolic link "My Documents" and creating a folder "My Documents" in "~/.wine/drive_c/users/user name/My Documents" did the trick for me.

PS. I'm surprised I couldn't seem to find this answer around given this question is 6 years old but maybe I just didn't look around enough, so please let me know if this post is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create a wrapper around `wine` that launched `wine` with a different `HOME`. E.g. you can create your own `~/bin/wine` (assuming `~/bin` is in your `PATH`), which sets:

```
#!/bin/sh
export "HOME=$HOME/.wine/home"
exec /usr/bin/wine "$@"
```

With an empty `WINEPREFIX` (`~/.wine/`), Wine will create the symbolic links to its own private home directory in `~/.wine/home/`.

You can expand this further to multiple wrappers for different Wine prefixes (e.g. for 32-bit vs. 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bubblewrap` installed, you can use its mechanisms to limit filesystem access.

**Example1.** You want wine to have access to `~/.wine` , `~/Downloads`, but nothing else. You may use this command then:

`bwrap --dev-bind / / --tmpfs ~ --bind ~/.wine ~/.wine --bind ~/Downloads ~/Downloads --new-session wine ~/.wine/path-to-your-program`

In the command above, we create a new namespace, bind the root `/`, bind an in-memory filesystem to `~`, and bind two directories above the `~`. Any changes done outside of those 2 directories will go into tmpfs and will be lost once bubblewrap (and your program) exits.

**Example2.** You don't want complex hierarchies, you just want all wine-related stuff to live in `~/.bubblewrap-wine-container`. And nowhere else. In this case, you can use:

`bwrap --dev-bind / / --bind ~/.bubblewrap-wine-container ~ --new-session wine path-to-your-program-relative-to-this-directory`

If you want to **forbid internet access** for any of those examples, add `--unshare-net` argument. Or maybe even `--unshare-all` to see if it'll launch. Refer to bubblewrap documentation for further details.