# How to isolate wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to figure out how to totally isolate a wine prefix (such as ~/.wine) to it's own folder. This is for security and morso simply for neatness. Obviously, the first step would be to totally disconnect the home/desktop integration in winecfg, right?

Is there some way I can run wine so that wine is limited in permissions to only read/write from the ./wine directory? (or just write permissions, if read is necessary for the dll integration?)

Basically, my question is this: Is it possible to isolate wine to ~/.wine? If so, how can this best be accomplished? I'm using wine 1.6, if it makes a difference.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278992/how-to-keep-wine-from-creating-directories-in-my-home-directory/279323#279323) re wine 'sandbox' mode, which is nothing like a true sandbox, but may be useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Wine needs access to its different parts: it reads from fonts in `/usr/share/wine`, a bunch of shared object libraries in `/usr/share`, not to mention the .dlls in the same place.

The best way to keep Wine totally isolated in `~/.wine` would be to compile the program from source in that directory. But it will always read information from the various software it uses.

The entire process for 32 bit:

```
sudo apt-get -y purge wine && sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove
cd ~/.wine
sudo apt-get -y build-dep wine1.4
apt-get source wine
cd wine1.4-1.4.1/
./tools/wineinstall
```